# Flickering/Flashing in navbar showing register and login button before showing user profile in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, navbar

I have a navbar component that will show login and register button, But If user is login it will show the user name. the user data get from the API and it must have `accessToken` to get the user data. So if the user login the `accessToken` will be set in localStorage and have access to get user data which will been show in navbar. The **Problem** is that user that already login will get flickering of login and register button if they refresh the page which will appear for a sec and then show user name. How can I stop it from showing flickering of the login and register button when user refresh the page?

This is the code:

**Navbar.jsx**

```
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useUserLoginDetailQuery } from "../pages/user/userApiSlice";

export const Navbar = () => {
  const { data: user, isLoading} = useUserLoginDetailQuery();


  return (
    <nav className="w-full h-28 flex flex-row px-16 items-center gap-28 border-b-blue-700 border-b-2">
      <Link to="/">
        <img src="/logo.svg" className="h-14" />
      </Link>
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-8">
        {user ? (
            <>
            {user.nama}
            </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Link
              to="/login"
              className="bg-none border-2 px-4 flex items-center h-10 text-blue-500 font-bold rounded-lg border-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white ease-in-out duration-200"
            >
              Login
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="/register"
              className="bg-blue-500 px-4 flex items-center h-10 border-2 border-blue-500 text-white font-bold rounded-lg  hover:bg-white hover:text-blue-500 ease-in-out duration-200"
            >
              Register
            </Link>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Can someone help me with this? I don't which are the right way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue so you can watch my code and i'll explain what i did.
like you are using `useUserLoginDetailQuery` I was using `useFirebase` custom hook

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsloggedIn] = useState();
  const firebase = useFirebase();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const user = await firebase?.user;
        if (user) {
          setIsloggedIn(true);
        } else if (user === undefined) {
          setIsloggedIn(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in auth", error);
      }
    })();
  }, [firebase?.user]);
```

So what was happening, the `isLoggedIn` was by default false so when the component firs renders it is false and the login button appears and then when i get the user information `isLoggedIn` set to true.
so to solve it i initialized `isLoggedIn` with empty state then I modified my hook to send undefined when user is not found

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user?.email);
      } else {
        setUser(undefined);
      }
```

and then conditionally checked if user is `undefined/ not found` (as i send `undefined` when user is not found)

```
        <>
          // as per first render the isLoggedIn will be null
          {isLoggedIn !== undefined ? (
           // on re-render of the component we will set isLoggedIn accordingly.
            isLoggedIn ? (
              <div></div>
            ) : (
              <NavLink to="/login">
                <li className="nav-item ">Login</li>
              </NavLink>
            )
          ) : (
            // showing loading till isLoggedIn is set to initialValue
            <div>Loading...</div>
          )}
        </>
```

I hope you understand what I've been trying to achieve. Any suggestions for improvement are always welcome.

Link for my Repo [Github](https://github.com/K-ash-ish/react-restaurant-app/blob/main/src/components/layout/Header.jsx)